# How to set local model repository - Tensorrt inference server with Minio

Tags: tensorflow, minio, tensorrt, kubeflow

Hi I want to setup Kubeflow - NVIDIA TensorRT inference server with repository located in MinIO.

I don't how to change **gs://inference-server-model-store/tf_model_store** to connect Minio.

```
ks init my-inference-server
cd my-inference-server
ks registry add kubeflow https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/tree/master/kubeflow
ks pkg install kubeflow/nvidia-inference-server
ks generate nvidia-inference-server iscomp --name=inference-server --image=nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorrtserver:19.04-py3 --modelRepositoryPath=gs://inference-server-model-store/tf_model_store
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NVIDIA TensorRT inference documentation on Kubeflow is not updated yet.

- Ksonnet is being [deprecated](https://blogs.vmware.com/cloudnative/2019/02/05/welcoming-heptio-open-source-projects-to-vmware/) after Heptio acquisition. Hence Kubeflow is 
  moving to [Kustomize](https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/2412).
- If you consider using Kustomize, you can configure S3 API with Kubeflow as described [here](https://github.com/kubeflow/examples/tree/master/mnist#using-s3). You should be able to use `s3://bucket/object` for models.